# Which of the physics dualities are closest in essence to the Spanier-Whitehead duality (with a subquestion)?

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, stable-homotopy, physics

First of all, what I want to ask is slightly more elaborate than what stands in the title (hence the subquestion).

I am telling this since as it is, the title contains a meaningful question, but it sounds very much like a superficial blind shot, so I want to provide some more motivation for asking it.

However there is one problem: what I am going to describe I have seen somewhere stated in detail, but cannot remember where, and cannot remember the details. OK, here it goes.

A concise way to formulate the SW-duality (or maybe I should actually say generalized Alexander duality?) is that a map $\varepsilon:X\wedge Y\to S^n$ with certain properties produces isomorphisms$$h^k(X)\to h_{n-k}(Y)$$for every cohomology theory $h$.

What I have seen somewhere is a very interesting geometric description of this map. Suppose that $\varepsilon$ comes from some embedding $i:X\hookrightarrow S^n$, with $Y$ homotopy equivalent to $S^n\setminus X$. Then, given an $h$-cocycle on $X$ one may ask whether it is in the image of $h^*(i):h^*(S^n)\to h^*(X)$. One may try to extend the cocycle from $X$ to larger and larger neighborhoods of $X$ in $S^n$. And if it is not in the image of $h^*(i)$ then at some point one encounters certain obstructions - say, the spots where the cocycle has been extended start to overlap and the extensions do not match on the overlaps. So if one does this extension as far as one can, certain singular "obstruction set" is carved out in $S^n\setminus X$, and the upshot is that for some nice $h$ this "obstruction set" (where the extended cocycle fails to be a genuine cocycle as it has some sort of singularities along this set) can be interpreted as an $h$-cycle in $S^n\setminus X$ (which is $\simeq Y)$, with different attempts giving rise to homologous cycles. (I believe I saw it worked out in detail at least for de Rham cohomology and $K$-theory, maybe also for cobordisms.)

> Now the subquestion: where could I see the above description?

So it is this description that inspired some vague analogies with things like branes, and hence the main question. I lost myself in zillion of dualities that physicists keep producing. Does the above extension obstruction interpretation of the duality resemble any of them?

Comment: It's been a while, but I think Alexander duality is the duality between charges and fields. I'm used to the situation where you have homology on X and cohomology on Y, though, so I'm not sure how to interpret your construction. I may try to work it through later for a real answer if no one beats me to it.

Comment: @AaronBergman In other words, in your context one has an explicit description of the inverse of the Alexander duality map. I have not seen this, and I think it is very interesting.

Comment: The only association I get for it is some sort of boundary value problem: if you can view $X$ as the boundary of some kind of compactification of its complement in the sphere, then, given a distribution (~cycle) on this boundary one seeks for a function (~cocycle) on the complement which limits (in some sense?) to this given distribution "at infinity"...

Comment: Unless I'm confused, what I'm thinking of is exactly the description of Alexander duality on Wikipedia. But may well be confused.